# NaN value in WordEmbedding

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, pytorch, embedding

In my model I have a simple word embedding done like this:

```
self.word_embedding = nn.Embedding(
            num_embeddings=len(self.word_vocab),       # 381
            embedding_dim=self.word_emb_size,          # 100
            padding_idx=self.word_vocab.pad,           # 0
        )
```

after the first batch iteration in the first epoch, its values begin to be NaN.
In the `forward()` it is used like this:

```
we = self.word_embedding(w)
```

where `w` is a tensor of shape `([50,61])` and its values are never NaN.

How can I do to solve this problem that I propagate the NaN values around the whole model?

Thank you!

EDIT:
Trying to retrace all the steps of the training I noticed that after the `loss.backward()` and before the `optimizer.step()` the minimum and maximum values for the word embedding gradient are already Nan:

```
for epoch in range(args.epochs):
    for batch in chunker(train, args.batch_size):
        # clear gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        # calculate loss
        loss = pat.train_conll(batch)
        # back propagate
        loss.backward()

        for name, params in pat.named_parameters():
            print("-->name:", name, "-->max_grad:", params.grad.max(), "-->min_grad:", params.grad.min())

        # optimize parameters
        optimizer.step()
```

output:

```
-->name: word_embedding.weight -->max_grad: tensor(nan, device='cuda:0') -->min_grad: tensor(nan, device='cuda:0')
```

EDIT2:
thanks to the helpful comment of @Nerveless_child.
The piece of code that was causing the problem is the following:

```py
class Norm(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, d_model, eps=1e-6):
        super().__init__()

        self.size = d_model
        # create two learnable parameters to calibrate normalisation
        self.alpha = nn.Parameter(torch.ones(self.size))
        self.bias = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(self.size))
        self.eps = eps

    def forward(self, x):
        norm = self.alpha * (x - x.mean(dim=-1, keepdim=True)) \
               / (x.std(dim=-1, keepdim=True) + self.eps) + self.bias
        return norm
```

used after a self-attention BiLSTM.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/embedding-returns-nan-issue/13209 or this https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/embedding-with-very-small-value-generate-nan-gradient/34539

Comment: More or less yes. I too did a normalization operation from a completely different part of the code and that involved a cancellation of the values that were interpreted as nan in my embedding. Thank you so much for your help, now I will edit my question with the offending piece of code.